# Как правильно изменить цикл LESS, чтобы получить после компиляции 100 селекторов а не 150

Tags: html, css, циклы, less

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

> Прогресс бар имеет три цвета в завимости от процентов. Желтый если меньше 51%, светло зеленый если 51% и больше, синий если 100%. Процент устанавливается в атрибут data-progress
>   Данные циклы компилят 100 селекторов с шириной от 1% до 100% и ещё 50 , в котором первые 50 другого цвета.
>    html

```
<div class="b-progress-bar" data-progress="25">
    <span class="b-progress-bar__line"></span>
</div>
```

less

```
@i: 0;
@increment:1%;
.loop (@i) when (@i <= 100) {
    &[data-progress="@{i}"] {
        .b-progress-bar__line {
            width: (@increment * @i);
        }
    }
    .loop(@i + 1);
}
.loop(@i);

.color (@i) when (@i <= 50) {
    &[data-progress="@{i}"] {
        .b-progress-bar__line {
            background-color: @pb-background-start;
        }
    }
    .color(@i + 1);
}
.color(@i);

&[data-progress="100"] {
    .b-progress-bar__line {
        background-color: @pb-background-end;
    }
}
```

Comment: В чем вопрос то?

Comment: Угадай мелодию...

Comment: Переделать цикл так ,чтобы вместо 150 компилировалось 100 селекторов. Грубо говоря мне нужно из двух циклов сделать 1 (с условием на то что первые 50 будут и иметь цвет  @pb-background-star

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для решения можно воспользоваться [CSS guard](http://lesscss.org/features/#css-guards-feature).

Для этого нужно написать `mixin` с ограничением соответствующим ограничению цикла `color`, в котором устанавливать нужный цвет:

```
.bg-start(@i) when (@i <= 50){
  background-color: @pb-background-start;
}
```

И далее использовать его как обычный `mixin`

```
&[data-progress="@{i}"] {
    .b-progress-bar__line {
        width: (@increment * @i);
        .bg-start(@i);
    }
}
```